# Regex for google referrer validation

Tags: c#, regex

I am totally new to Regex and have been trying to do this with little success.

Basically what I want to do is to create a regex that matches any google domain such as Google.com, Google.co.uk, etc.

So far I have `^http://www.google\.com/.*$`, but this only matches Google.com. How can I modify it to allow any extension besides `com`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use alternation, but then you would have to supply all TLDs you want to allow:

```
^http://www\.google\.(?:com|co\.uk|de|es)/.*$
```

Add more options separated by pipes. Alternatively, you could allow **any** TLD (whether valid or not) with this:

```
^http://www\.google\.[a-z.]+/.*$
```

However this would also match something like `http://www.google.myowndomain.com/`. I don't think there would be any approach that allows only valid domains without listing them all.

By the way, if you want to make that slash and the path/query at the end optional, change that to one of the following:

```
^http://www\.google\.(?:com|co\.uk|de|es)(?:/.*)?$
^http://www\.google\.[a-z.]+(?:/.*)?$
```

And then you could go another step further and make the `www.` optional:

```
^http://(?:www\.)?google\.(?:com|co\.uk|de|es)(?:/.*)?$
^http://(?:www\.)?google\.[a-z.]+(?:/.*)?$
```

You see, matching all possible but valid URLs for a given problem is not an easy task, but one that needs careful consideration ;).

Depending on the language you are using there might be better options with built-in URL-parsing functions. In PHP for instance, this would be a much easier approach:

```
$domain = parse_url($urlStr, PHP_URL_HOST);
$isGoogle = preg_match('/^(?:www\.)?google\.[a-z.]+/', $domain);
```

Or (since this is not perfect anyway, as outlined above) you could abandon regex altogether and do the check like this:

```
$isGoogle = strpos($domain, 'google.') !== false;
```

Comment: Works perfect man. I used your second solution as listing all of the TLD is too much. I will take the small risk of having a google.mydomain.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am forced to use Regex because I am using it in an IIS Url Rewrite module.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper all right, that's fair enough. I'll leave it there anyway, should somebody else with a different setting stumble upon the same problem.